# How best should a Wcf service return different objects for the same method

Tags: c#, wcf

I have the following interface for my Wcf service;

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [XmlSerializerFormat]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/GetTypes", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    object GetTypes(RequestObject RequestObject);

}
```

My service looks like this;

```
public class Service : IService
{
   public static GetTypes(RequestObject RequestObject)
   {
        if(RequestObject.Validate)
        {
            //create a new response obj, and return it
            ResponseObj oResponseObj = new ResponseObj();
            //get some data from data source and populate object, then return it
            return oResponseObj;
        }
        else
        {
            //error response
            ErrorResponseObj oErrorResponseObj = new ErrorResponseObj();
            oErrorResponseObj.ErrorId = 1;
            oErrorResponseObj.ErrorMessage = "There was a error";
            return oErrorResponseObj;
        }
   }
}
```

My response object is

```
[DataContract]
public class ResponseObj
{
    [DataMember]        
    public int Id {get;set;}

    [DataMember] 
    public List<string> Names {get;set;}
}
```

I also have a error response like

```
[DataContract]
public class ErrorResponseObj
{
    [DataMember]        
    public int ErrorId {get;set;}
    [DataMember]
    public string ErrorMessage {get;set;}
    [DataMember]
    public string MessageImportance {get;set;}
}
```

How best should I be returning these different objects to the Wcf method.  Should I be returning the type object ?  Or are there better alternatives, or is this the correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to do such a thing is to use a [`FaultContractAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.faultcontractattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Fault contracts allow you to specify alternate responses which will be returned inside a SOAP `Fault`.  Philippe Truche gives a good example of how these look on the wire [on his blog](https://philippetruche.wordpress.com/tag/faultexception/).

Example interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(ErrorResponseObj))]
    ResponseObj GetObj();
}
```

Service:

```
class Service : IService
{
    public ResponseObj GetObj()
    {
        if (success)
        {
            return new ResponseObj();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new FaultException<ErrorResponseObj>(new ErrorResponseObj() 
            {
                ErrorMessage = "Something Happened"
            })
        }
    }
}
```

The client can then handle the fault by catching `FaultException<ErrorResponseObj>`:

```
var serviceProxy = new ServiceProxy();

try 
{
    var dataObj = serviceProxy.GetObj();
}
catch (FaultException<ErrorResponseObj> error)
{
    ErrorResponseObj detail = error.Detail;
    Console.WriteLine(detail.ErrorMessage);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can aggregate it into one type:

```
[DataContract]
public class ResponseObj
{
   [DataMember]        
   public int ErrorId {get;set;}
   [DataMember]
   public string ErrorMessage {get;set;}
   [DataMember]
   public string MessageImportance {get;set;}
   [DataMember]
   public int Id {get;set;}
   [DataMember]
   public List<string> Name {get;set;}
}
```

And then you would check if ErrorId is > 0, otherwise there were no errors.

Another approach is to throw a Fault Exception in the WCF service so it would be handled in 
the client side:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2011/01/14/wcf-spike-faultcontract-faultexception-lt-tdetail-gt-and-validation.aspx

Comment: I just added an extra alternative to my answer.